# how to read the txt file from the database(line by line)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, filestream

i have stored the txt file to sql server database .
i need to read the txt file line by line to get the content in it.
 my code :

```
DataTable dtDeleteFolderFile = new DataTable();
dtDeleteFolderFile = objutility.GetData("GetTxtFileonFileName", new object[] { ddlSelectFile.SelectedItem.Text }).Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDeleteFolderFile.Rows)
{
  name = dr["FileName"].ToString();
  records = Convert.ToInt32(dr["NoOfRecords"].ToString());
  bytes = (Byte[])dr["Data"];
}

FileStream readfile = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("txtfiles/" + name), FileMode.Open);

StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(readfile);
string line = "";
line = streamreader.ReadLine();
```

but here i have used the `FileStream` to read from the Particular path. but i have saved the txt file in byte format into my Database. how to read the txt file using the byte[] value to get the txt file content, instead of using the Path value.

Comment: @Ranjana: You can edit your questions, no need to ask them again!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657583/how-to-read-the-txt-file-from-databasebyte-to-filestream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given th fact that you have the file in a byte array, you can make use of [MemoryStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)

Something like

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
    }    
}
```

Also make sure to use [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)

> Defines a scope, outside of which an
>   object or objects will be disposed.
>
> The using statement allows the
>   programmer to specify when objects
>   that use resources should release
>   them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the
>   IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which
>   should release the object's resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this at the end of your `foreach`:

```
String txtFileContent = Encoding.Unicode.GetString((Byte[])dr["Data"]);
```